# Разделять массив из файла по нескольким символам

Tags: javascript

Знатоки, нужен хелп. Перебираю массив из файла. Элементы заносятся по принципу через каждый знак запятой новый элемент. Далее заносится в div с определённым классом.

```
 $.get("./files/city_list.txt", function(data) {      
    let doctors = data.split(',');  
    $.each(doctors, function() {
        $('.selectCity__list').append('<div class="selectCity__item">'+this+'</div>');
    });
```

Вопрос в том, можем ли мы разделять еще по знаку ";" и заносить в другой div с другим классом, при этом не нарушив последовательности? Заранее извиняюсь за тупой вопрос, в js не силён

Comment: и ',' и ';' в одной строке?

Comment: В файле данные будут по такому принципу test,
test1,
test2;
test3,
test4;

Comment: и что в вашей строке должно быть в одном, а что в другом диве?

Comment: Значения до запятой должны падать в  $('.selectCity__list').append('<div class="selectCity__item">'+this+'</div>');, а значение до ";" должно попадать в $('.selectCity__list').append('<div class="selectCity__groups">'+this+'</div>');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const divComma = document.querySelector('.comma');
const divSemicolon = document.querySelector('.semicolon');
const pastItem = (target, txt, cls) => target.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li class="${cls}">${txt.replace(/[,;]$/, '')}</li>`);

'aa,bb,cc;dd,ee,ff;gg;hh,ii;'.match(/[^;,]+[,;]/g).forEach(s => {
  if (s.indexOf(',') !== -1) {
    pastItem(divComma, s, 'selectCity__list');
  } else {
    pastItem(divSemicolon, s, 'selectCity__groups');
  }
});
```

```css
.selectCity__list {
  color: #060;
}

.selectCity__groups {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<ul class="comma"></ul>
<ul class="semicolon"></ul>
```

Или такой, более расширяемый вариант

```js
const pastItem = (d, txt) => d.target.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li class="${d.cls}">${txt.replace(/[,;]$/, '')}</li>`);

const templ = {
  comma: {
    cls: 'selectCity__list',
    target: document.querySelector('.comma')
  },
  semicolon: {
    cls: 'selectCity__groups',
    target: document.querySelector('.semicolon')
  }
};

const str = 'aa,bb,cc;dd,ee,ff;gg;hh,ii;';
for (const match of str.matchAll(/(?<comma>[^;,]+[,])|(?<semicolon>[^;,]+[;])/g)) {
  for (const [k, txt] of Object.entries(match.groups)) {
    if (txt && templ.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      pastItem(templ[k], txt);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.selectCity__list {
  color: #060;
}

.selectCity__groups {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<ul class="comma"></ul>
<ul class="semicolon"></ul>
```

Comment: а как мы можем вместо 'aa,bb,cc;dd,ee,ff;gg;hh,ii;' получить данные из файла?

Comment: @TinturSoft, так в вашем же вопросе есть код получения -  `$.get( ... )`. Если файл находится на вашем же сервере и путь к нему указан верно, то в переменной `data` и есть ваша строка

Comment: всё, понял, огромное спасибо!